# Getting Run time error cannot open 'xxxx' from ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.4

I am trying to create a script to add values to a new field in a table based on the  text values of another field in the same table. Here is my code:

```
import os
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

arcpy.env.workspace = "c:/Myfiles/geodatabase"
updateFields = ["fieldname1","fieldname2"]

def updateweight(filename,fields):
  with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(filename,fields) as cursor:
    for row in rows:
      if row[0] == "unrestricted":
        row[1] = 3
      elif row[0] == "restricted":
        row[1] = 2
      elif row[0] == "severely restricted":
        row[1] = 0
  Cursor.updateRow(row)
  del cursor

updateweight("shape_file_name", updateFields)
```

When I run this I get:

```
Run time error
File "<string>" line 1 in <module>
File "<string?" line 11 in updateweight cannot open 'shape_file_name'
```

I've tried including the .dbf file extension in the file name and also tried calling the assigning a variable to the filename and calling it that way.

I was unable to copy and paste the code directly because it is on a work machine in a secure environment, so there my be some typos in the code. I wrote it as a function so I can make it into a more generic tool once I've tested it.

Comment: I assume you mean feature class not shapefile. You can't store shapefiles in a file geodatabase (FGDB).  You can have feature classes in an FGDB (or in a feature dataset in an FGDB).  If you have copied an actual shapefile (i.e the "shape_file_name.shp", "shape_file_name.shx" and "shape_file_name.dbf" files) into the file geodatabase directory, then that def. won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that error is telling you that it cannot find a shapefile named "shape_file_name" in the current workspace.

I suspect that you may have set a variable named `shape_file_name` in code outside what you have presented and then tried to refer to it as "shape_file_name" instead of `shape_file_name`.

Comment: I used "shape_file_name" here as a generic name, in the script I called the actual name, sorry if that caused confusion.

Comment: @GregNoland perhaps review https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers

Comment: I can see the shapefile in a feature dataset in the geodatabbase in arc catalog.

Comment: @GregNoland Shapefiles cannot exist within geodatabases but feature classes can, and feature classes can also exist within feature.datasets of geodatabases.

Comment: Thanks for link, I'll keep it handy for my next question. I guess I wasn't fully aware of the difference between the two, which is probably the problem. Now that I think of it, it is likely a feature class. Should exporting it as a shapefile, then calling the correct path fix the issue?

Comment: @GregNoland From the code that you have presented and from the gaps in what I know of your data I cannot advise.